# Handle separate touches inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, touch

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a UIButton and a UIImageView.  I want the UIButton and UIImageView objects to handle touches outside of the UITableViewDelegate's `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
@implementation CustomTableViewController
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      // handle cell selected
    }
@end
```

My UITableViewCell:

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

    - (id)init {
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [image addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked)]];
        [image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

    /*
     * I want these to be called instead of tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
     * when the button or image are tapped and I want
     * tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to be called when any other part of
     * the cell is tapped.
     */

    - (void)buttonClicked {
        // not called
    }

    - (void)imageClicked {
        // not called
    }
@end
```

How do I get buttonClicked and imageClicked to be called instead of the controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CustomTableViewCell` we had the following:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.button frame], [touch locationInView:self])){
        [self buttonClicked];
        /* Added this to resolve the issue
         * [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:nil];
         */
    }
    else if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.container frame], [touch locationInView:self])) {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else{
        [self imageClicked];
        /* Added this to resolve the issue
         * [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:nil];
         */
    }

}
```

We added [super touchesCancelled] in the first and third condition, which seems to have accomplished what we wanted, but it seems wrong to call `touchesCancelled` ourselves. Is there a better way to handle those cases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do, so this may or may not help, but there is a property called `Delays Content Touches` in the storyboard/xib file. This property basically says, it will take the table/scrollview into consideration before the subviews, but if you uncheck that it will take the subviews into consideration before the scrolling.

Of course this gives way to other errors, like being able to touch a button/image while it's scrolling, but if that doesn't matter then this could be your solution.

For best effects make sure the `canCancelContentTouches` property (`Cancellable Content Touches` in the storyboard) is set to YES (or selected) this basically says if you press down on a button and then drag your finger that the scroll view will start scrolling and will cancel the touch event.

You can read more about the property in the [UIScrollView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches)